# Http request not authenticated after passing through Zuul

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I tried to send a Javascript XHR request that includes a

```
'Authorization: Basic base64encodedCredentials'
```

header through a Zuul proxy. Behind the proxy is my Spring Security Server that exposes an endpoint which is secured by Basic HTTP authentication. My server reacts with a 401 ("unauthorized"). If I send the same request via curl, all is well.

Using a network monitoring tool, I observed that the header Zuul is sending looks like this:

`'authorization: Basic base64encodedCredentials'` (notice the lowercase 'a' in 'authorization')

After I had a look at the source code of `BasicAuthenticationFilter` in Spring Security, I suspect that the lowercase 'a' is the reason why my XHR request is not authenticated by my server.

Is this a bug in Zuul ? What do you think ?

Edit: http header names are actually case insensitive.

So Zuul is not to blame. What else has then caused the authentication to fail ?

Comment: http headers are case insensitive and so is `request.getHeader(...)`. It must be something else.

Comment: You're right. I checked this by calling request.getHeader('Authorization') in a Zuul "route" filter. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at the wrong place.

For everyone stumbling over this, I'll depict what happened:

My Zuul route was set to

```
http://<host>/<securityContext>/auth/token
```

while it should have been set to

`http://<host>/<securityContext>/oauth/token` (notice the extra 'o')

The wicked reaction of the Spring Security Server was not to respond with a '404' ("not found") to the wrong route, but with a '401' ("unauthorized"). This lead me to the assumption that there is something wrong with the authentication header (or some other header for that matter).

As of now, I don't know why the Security Server responded that way. It seems to me that there is actually an endpoint exposed under `/auth/token`.